# Nodejs - MongoDB Query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, ejs

I have a little problem with my Thesis project.
 I have a **mongodb** database with abour 400k entries styled like this:(i've translated the variables so if theres any typo, sorry);

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var work_schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  worktype: String,
  ordernumber: String,
  art_code: String,
  qta: String,
  number_of_operatos: String,
  1_op_code: String,
  2_op_code: String,
  3_op_code: String,
  4_op_code: String,
  phase: String,
  notes: String,
  continued: String, //just a flag
  date_start: String, // DD-MM-YYYY
  date_end: String,   // DD-MM-YYYY
  time_start: String, //HH:MM:SS
  time_end: String,   //HH:MM:SS
  datainiziopart: String, //this is the date parsed like this YYYYMMDD i needed it for another purpose
  datafinepart: String, //this is the date parsed like this YYYYMMDD i needed it for another purpose
  cronsec: String,
  cronsec1: String,
  cronsec2: String,
  cronsec3: String,
  cronsec4: String,
  cronsec5: String,
  cronsec6: String,
  cronsec7: String,
  operationtimesec: String,
  designtimesec: String,
  totalecausalisec: String,
  ke: String,

  author: {
    id: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User"
    },
    username: String,
    codicereparto: {
      id: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Reparti"
      },
      nomereparto: String,
      descrizionereparto: String
    }
  }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("Work", work_schema);
```

As you can see the schema is not small at all, and having more than 400k entries, i need to query them when exporting/showing.
 I used the limit function to show the latest entries.

I want to create a Page with a datepicker to query the data, or using the

> date_start: String, // DD-MM-YYYY

or using the

> datainiziopart // YYYYMMDD like <>=

Can you help me write the **nodejs** code to render a page with the result?

I use express if that can help.
 i tried to do this

```
router.get("/risultati", function(req, res) {
      Request.getAllRequestListingsCb(function (err, docs){
          res.render('pannello/risultati', { rL: docs });
      });
});


router.post("/ricercautente", function(req, res) {
  var data = req.body.filtro;
  var datadivisa = data.split(' - ');

  var datestart= moment(datadivisa[0], 'DD-MM-YYYY').format('DD-MM-YYYY');
  var dateend= moment(datadivisa[1], 'DD-MM-YYYY').format('DD-MM-YYYY');
  //res.redirect("/pannello/utentetutti");
  module.exports.getAllRequestListings = function (callback) {
      var query = {"datainizio": {"$gte": new Date(datainizio), "$lt": new Date(datafine)}};
      Lavori.find(query, callback);
  };
  res.redirect('pannello/risultati');

});
```

```
<div class="" align=center>
  <form  action="/ricercautente" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="filtro" id="filtro"  />
    <button class="pure-button pure-button-warning" name="" id="" type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div
```

and on another page

```
  <tbody>
      <% lavoritrovati.forEach(function(lavoro){ %>
      <tr>
        <td>          <%=lavoro.author.codicereparto.nomereparto%>        </td>
        <td>          <%=lavoro.tipodilavoro%>        </td>
        <td>          <%=lavoro.ordineproduzione %>        </td>
        <td>          <%=lavoro.codicearticolo %>        </td>
        <td>          <%=lavoro.quantita %>        </td>
        <td>          <%=lavoro.noperatori %>        </td>
        <td>          <%=lavoro.codoperatori%>        </td>
        <td>          <%=lavoro.codoperatori2%>        </td>
        <td>          <%=lavoro.codoperatori3%>        </td>
        <td>          <%=lavoro.codoperatori4%>        </td>
        <td>          <%=lavoro.fase %>        </td>
        <td>          <%=lavoro.note %>        </td>
        <td>          <%=lavoro.datainizio %>        </td>
        <td>          <%=lavoro.timestart %>        </td>
        <td>          <%=lavoro.datafine %>        </td>
        <td>          <%=lavoro.timeend %>        </td>
        <td>          <%=lavoro.continuato %>        </td>
        <td>          <%=lavoro.cronsec %>        </td>
        <td>          <%=lavoro.cronsec1 %>        </td>
        <td>          <%=lavoro.cronsec2 %>        </td>
        <td>          <%=lavoro.cronsec3 %>        </td>
        <td>          <%=lavoro.cronsec4 %>        </td>
        <td>          <%=lavoro.cronsec5 %>        </td>
        <td>          <%=lavoro.cronsec6 %>        </td>
        <td>          <%=lavoro.cronsec7 %>        </td>
        <td>          <%=lavoro.designtimesec %>        </td>
        <td>          <%=lavoro.operationtimesec %>        </td>
        <td>          <%=lavoro.ke %>        </td>
<% }); %>
```

Comment: Please @Roman , review this. 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
You should provide at least a minimum verifiable example of your current code to solve it. We are not here to make other's homework, but we will be very glad of helping with your current code. May you paste it?

Comment: @AlejandroTeixeiraMuñoz sorry first time posting, if that can be helpful i can post a github copy, but most of the project uses italian variables or text so i was unsure if it can be helpful

Comment: It's not neccesary to post the full code. Post at least, your call to Express, and the main part of the HTML view/controller where you are using in the front,

yes, this is a start point

Comment: The query for mongoose seems to be ok. Please show your call to Express function!! what are you sending? Are you sure the split functions are working as you expect??

Comment: 3 opts:
1.- Make one api call for each "page", selecting the date and sending the date to the api, every call
2.- Make server side pagination - This means that the function in mongoose will select some part of the data, and will give it to you (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43925662/mongoose-pagination-from-server-side)
2.- Make client side pagination - This means that the function in your front javascript, will be the one in charge of paginating: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10816073/how-to-do-paging-in-angularjs
What do you think is the best for you?

Comment: This last comment considers that you want to create like pages to navigate around the big results. If you need to create then the datepicker, tell me

Comment: if i understood correctly the client side pagination will load all my database and show only the requested ones.

Comment: Yep. It creates more "wait" time on the request response, but just one DB call, and is faster when later rendering it (as it is in memory loaded). The other one, on server, is just less heavier for the client. This is just your election/needs

Comment: I think you can try to measure the full response size in KB and this will give you an idea of the memory load you are creating on the web browser. If it's not too big.. go for it. (Angular UI Bootstrap - Pagination Directive) if under angular

Comment: if i use my   datainiziopart: String, //this is the date parsed like this YYYYMMDD and use <>= greater, smaller or equal operators to fix my query? maybe its the moment date forman that creates query problem. I need to create this "one"page table so my chart js javascript code can read the data

Comment: You can check the exact parameteres you are sending on webinspectors from browsers https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/open in network section

Comment: Did you make any progress ? (I'm working right now so I cannot be very very close, sorry)

Comment: Nope still still stuck.. Don't worry I'll. Figure it out